# Get file path in the ondata event

Tags: filepond

I'm using the ondata event to add data to the formData, but I need the relative file path in there (in case someone uploads a folder, so I can recreate the same structure on the server after upload, e.g `/myFolder/fileploaded.jpg`)

How does one get _relativePath in the ondata event ?

```js
FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        url: 'http://192.168.0.100',
        timeout: 7000,
        process: {
            url: './process',
            ondata: (formData) => {
                let fullPath = ''; // Need _relativePath here
                formData.append('Hello', 'World');
                return formData;
            }
        },

    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can add the relative path to the file metadata object, it's posted along with the file object?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to filepond, I'm not sure what you're referring to. Is it this https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-metadata/ (In which case I don't see either how to get relative path there) ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I didn't see in the [docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/) that there is a more advanced process function:

```js
FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        process:(fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {

            // fieldName is the name of the input field
            // file is the actual file object to send
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);

            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', 'url-to-api');

            // Should call the progress method to update the progress to 100% before calling load
            // Setting computable to false switches the loading indicator to infinite mode
            request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
                progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
            };

            // Should call the load method when done and pass the returned server file id
            // this server file id is then used later on when reverting or restoring a file
            // so your server knows which file to return without exposing that info to the client
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                    // the load method accepts either a string (id) or an object
                    load(request.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    // Can call the error method if something is wrong, should exit after
                    error('oh no');
                }
            };

            request.send(formData);
            
            // Should expose an abort method so the request can be cancelled
            return {
                abort: () => {
                    // This function is entered if the user has tapped the cancel button
                    request.abort();

                    // Let FilePond know the request has been cancelled
                    abort();
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```